# audio tag not working with phoneGap

Tags: android, html, cordova

i'm developping a game with HTML5 i'm trying to add sound , it works when i test it in the browser but it's a mobile game so when i test it in the emulator via PhoneGap the sound is not working .

here's my code :
Html:

```
   <audio id="buttonover">
   <source src="sounds/cartoon008.ogg" ></source>
   </audio>
```

JavaScript :

```
 sndCollide = document.getElementById('buttonover');
 sndCollide.play();
```

Comment: Which browser in your emulator? Froyo, Gingerbread ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923187/html5-audio-phonegap-android

Comment: @hkutluay  i'm not running the application in a brower, i'm generating
an APK extention it's an android application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sound response of native audio tag is **very slow** in mobile browsers.

So you can use a **phonegap native sound** system

the javascript code for it is

> src="sounds/cartoon008.ogg"
>
> > var soundObj = new Media(src,onSuccess,onError);
> >
> > > soundObj.play();

also kindly check that ogg files are supported in mobile.

you have to write a overriding functions for onSuccess and onnError.

Comment: i test it but i'm getting errors : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400141/using-the-media-object-to-record-and-play-back-audio-files-on-a-device