# Using The Media object to record and play back audio files on a device

Tags: audio, cordova

Hi i try to use the phoneGap Media object to play audio content but i'm getting this error 
Uncaught ReferenceError:Media is not defined i'm getting this example of code from phonegap Documentation http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html
[image]

I'm using the code below :

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Media Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        playAudio("http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3");
    }

    // Audio player
    //
    var my_media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;

    // Play audio
    //
    function playAudio(src) {
        // Create Media object from src
        my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();

        // Update my_media position every second
        if (mediaTimer == null) {
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                // get my_media position
                my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                    // success callback
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                        }
                    },
                    // error callback
                    function(e) {
                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    // Pause audio
    // 
    function pauseAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.pause();
        }
    }

    // Stop audio
    // 
    function stopAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.stop();
        }
        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback 
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Set audio position
    // 
    function setAudioPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" 
    onclick="playAudio('http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_  
    _rockGuitar.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="pauseAudio();">Pause Playing Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="stopAudio();">Stop Playing Audio</a>
    <p id="audio_position"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea please , thank u very much

Comment: Did you change the reference to phonegap.js to match the version you are using?

Comment: this is me again i find the problem this code works find it just was a problem with the LoadUrl method used in the activity i used the wrong url

Comment: Mr @SimonMacDonald is this the best way to animate a game add sound to buttons , flipping cards ...

Comment: Yeah, you can create multiple Media objects and play the sounds when you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link u r providing for playing sound is not working properly when I am opening the link in a browser I m not able to play sound.

So kindly store ur rockGuitar.mp3 inside your assets/www folder and while playing that file provide the src of the file as

```
src= "/android_asset/www/rockGuitar.mp3";
newMedia= new Media(src,onSuccess1,onError);
```

Or provide working link in the src of sound.

Comment: i test it and it works fine with chrome in your case i think it's a problem with the browser thank you